# Weird BIND9 Behavior

Tags: dns, bind

This problem has been bothering me for 2 days and hope you guys can give me some advice.

I try to set up outlook.com as my mail service. And of course it require me to update my MX record to point to Microsoft's server.

And now, the problem is, no matter how I set the MX record, the value always end with my domain name. For example my domain is `abc.com` and I'm using `BIND 9.7.3`. Please refer the script below. But when I query using `nslookup` either using command line or online tool. I get the exchange value as `a2d53f710931b4f6.pamx1.hotmail.com.abc.com`. I tried the same thing on another server at a different datacenter and it turns out to be fine.

Do you guys have any idea what's wrong here? Is it my new server's `BIND` default setting problem or the network provider setting that effect it?

```
$ORIGIN abc.com.
@   IN  SOA ns1.abc.com. postmaster.abc.com. (
            2013022427
            8H
            2H
            7D
            1D )
                IN              NS              ns1.abc.com.
                IN              NS              ns2.abc.com.
                IN              MX              10 a2d53f710931b4f6.pamx1.hotmail.com
```

Comment: yes, same thing happens here, but I just ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by adding an dot (`.`) at the end of the MX record. Example:

```
a2d53f710931b4f6.pamx1.hotmail.com.

            IN              MX              10 a2d53f710931b4f6.pamx1.hotmail.com.
```